# How to diagnose the cause of download interruptions?

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, internet, safari

We moved a few months ago, and our wifi has become very, very unreliable. We use the same provider & same hardware.  Some days I have to reboot the modem several times, other days we have no problem. Often, even if the modem doesn't go offline our downloads are interrupted. In Chrome, the message I get then is: "The download was taking too long and was stopped by the network." In Safari it's a slightly different message amounting to the same.

What could cause that?

Comment: Possibly your new place has more walls and things for your wifi signal to go through? You could try running an ethernet cable or using one of those ethernet through wall outlet adapters.

Comment: Just how often does the modem go offline? You did not even mention the method that your ISP is providing net? If it is "cable" it can be the signal is not strong enough, bad or old cables to the modem. you could test the modem closer to the connection box, or with less splits, or run temporary cabling bypassing the built-in cables to see if that helps. The cable company has meters that can determine the ammount of DB of loss through your cabling in seconds, although they may very well say there is "enough" even if it is pretty sad.

Comment: @Eric F - proximity to the modem has no impact.

Comment: How many people are connected to router?

Comment: Do you have network problems when connected directly?

Comment: What makes you think it's your Wi-Fi and not your broadband link?

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since JDelage states "Some days I have to reboot the modem several times", the issue is between the modem and the service provider, i.e. bad modem, bad connection at the cable, or other issue father away. This would seem to be a problem the service provider should fix. This has nothing to do with WiFi or browser, *per se*.